# Libgdx thinks keyboard always being pressed

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to handle keyboard input using `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed();`. At first I handled `asdw` input, and all went just fine. But when a few lines below I tried to handle keys input, it didn't worked.

When I debug it, I can see that it always counts the ifs as true (in other words, he acts like all the arrows are always pressed), **but this doesn't occur with the "asdw" check.**

When I tried to change the keys to regular letters, the problem still occurred.

The code:

```
public void update(float deltaTime)

    handleDebugInp(deltaTime);
    updateTestSprites(deltaTime);
    cameraH.update(deltaTime);
}

private void handleDebugInp(float dt) {//for enabled long pressed buttons
    if(Gdx.app.getType() != ApplicationType.Desktop)//proceed with debugging only on pc
        return;

    /*keys movement*/
    float spriteSpeed = 5 * dt;//moves 5 meters per second

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A))//if A is pressed
        moveCurrSprite(-spriteSpeed, 0);//move left
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D))//if D is pressed
        moveCurrSprite(spriteSpeed, 0);//right
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W))//if W is pressed
        moveCurrSprite(0, spriteSpeed);//up
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S))//if S is pressed
        moveCurrSprite(0, -spriteSpeed);//down

    /*Camera movment*/
    //speed
    float cameraSpeed = 5 * dt;
    float accelerationFactor = 5;

    //sprint
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SHIFT_LEFT));
        cameraSpeed *= accelerationFactor;

    //movement
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT));
        moveCamera(-cameraSpeed, 0);
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT));
        moveCamera(cameraSpeed, 0);
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP));
        moveCamera(0, -cameraSpeed);
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN));
        moveCamera(0, cameraSpeed);

}
private void moveCamera(float x, float y) {
    x += cameraH.getPosition().x;
    y += cameraH.getPosition().y;

    cameraH.setPosition(x, y);
}
```

If someone might know what is the problem, I'll be happy if he'll let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you a hint.  There is a stray `;` on one of these two lines:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT));
    moveCamera(-cameraSpeed, 0);
```

(and you pasted the same problem onto the other lines).

Comment: Ahh. hahah, my bad.
Thanks!